# ransack in rails with complex controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, controller, ransack

I'm trying to use ransack in my rails app, but I can't put it in my tasks controller without screwing up the controller action itself.

What I wanna do is calling ransack on @user.tasks_uncompleted not on Task.all.

I tried to call ransack on Task.all first and then chain the tasks_uncompleted (without current_user) with defined def ransackable_scopes method for tasks_uncompleted, but I couldn't pull off even that one.

Here is the code:

user.rb

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id"
has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id"

def tasks_uncompleted
  tasks_uncompleted = assigned_tasks.uncompleted.order("created_at DESC")
  tasks_uncompleted += executed_tasks.uncompleted.order("created_at DESC")
  tasks_uncompleted.sort_by { |h| h[:created_at] }.reverse!
end
```

task.rb

```
 belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
 belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"
```

tasks_controller

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @tasks = @user.tasks_uncompleted.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```